# Использование тире в переведенном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, переводы

Переводя текст на русский язык, столкнулся с небольшой проблемой в, казалось бы, простом по виду предложении. Выглядит оно так: "Ты (—) уже другая..."
Собственно, сам вопрос заключается именно в наличии/отсутствии тире.

Answer (score 3):

Тире в таком предложении считается **интонационным**. Это значит, что оно не является обязательным по правилам, но ставится при наличии паузы. Это **авторское тире.**

Но здесь уже автор может задать следующий вопрос: **как определить необходимость  паузы?** В конце концов, пауза при постановке знаков препинания — это ориентир не всегда надежный (в предложении бывают произносительные паузы, которые никак не обозначаются).

И вот здесь нужно перейти **к интонационному анализу.** Пауза —это не только остановка голоса, но еще и обязательное **логическое ударение** на предшествующем слове, а это уже можно **вычислить по контексту**.

Сравним два примера:

(1) ***Весь вопрос в тебЕ. ТЫ — уже другая...***

В первом примере  на местоимение ***ты***  может падать логическое ударение, соответственно,  после него в этом случае делается пауза, обозначаемая тире.

Но вариант без паузы  и тире тоже возможен, то есть задача имеет два решения. ***Весь вопрос в тебЕ. Ты уже другАя...***

**Если совсем коротко, то постановка тире зависит от логического ударения:** если хотите выделить ударением подлежащее  ***ты***, то тире ставится; если хотите выделить сказуемое ***другая***, то тире не ставится.

(2) ***Ты изменИлась, ты уже другАя...***

Во втором примере **ударением подчеркиваются другие (однородные по смыслу)** слова (*изменилась, другая*), поэтому пауза после местоимения ***ты*** не делается.